# On-Send feature in OWA

Tags: outlook-web-addins

> Office Store - You can't publish Outlook add-ins that use the on send
>   feature to the Office Store. Add-ins that use the on send event will
>   fail Office Store validation.

What is the road map for on-send feature? On which platforms will it be available and will succeed when published in Office Store?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a little bit of info about what your add-in intends to do? there may be an alternate solution to your problem.

Comment: We are developing email protection/encryption add-in/plugins for all OSes and platforms. Developed as cross platform it will have potential to deeply impact global cyber crime. So the more accessible the plugin is bigger impact will be. And that is the value of publishing on-send enabled add-in in the Store. I will appreciate to talk privately on our plans and how Microsoft can help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no plans to support the On-Send feature in store add-ins at this time.

Comment: This is just annoying... as base statement from microsoft:

Outlook add-ins are integrations built by third parties into Outlook using the new web technologies based platform. Outlook add-ins have three key aspects:

The same add-in and business logic works across desktop (Outlook for Windows and Mac), web (Office 365 and Outlook.com), and mobile.
...

Your Statement is against the intension of this technology. It somehow looks like microsoft itself does not know what do with the javascript api.... Sadly! because it is great idea